# In react redux ,how to store the array of objects in the store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How to store the array of objects in redux store.. And also what should I specify the initial state  in the createSlice .
[this datas want to store in my redux store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiIHm.jpg)

[this is my createSlice.
In this what should I write the initial state and also reducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ6jQ.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service and we can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see. Please edit your post to include your attempt as a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array of objects in your reducer's initial state like this:

```
initialState: {
  foodData: [
    {
      id: 1,
      productName: "",
      image: "",
      price: "",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      productName: "",
      image: "",
      price: "",
    },
  ]
}
```

I recommend you take a look at the documentation [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start)